# python dataframe column value match with list (in)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, contains

```
target_sample = ['Apple','milk','nacho','cracker','potato','pear']
df = pd.DataFrame({'query':['apple watch','choco milk','nacho','banana milk','cracker','potatochips','pear juice','suncream']})
```

and I want to get the dataframe that contains the target sample element.
The result should be

---

| query |
| --- |
| apple watch |
| choco milk |
| nacho |
| banana milk |
| cracker |
| potatochips |
| pear juice |

I know the way after creating the empty list and for loop with contains..
but want to know more fast and efficient way or function like isin

** I tried isin also, but it is not the result that I wanted to

```
pattern = '|'.join(map(str, target_sample))
sample_df[sample_df['query'].str.contains(fr'\b(?:{pattern})\b')]
```

**the result code above is almost okay but if the values doesn't have the space, it doesn't work, which means this code doesn't get the potatochips at all.**

```
for t in target_sample:
for query in df['query']:
    if t in query:
        print(query)
```

is the code above the only way to filter this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note that you can make the filtering case insensitive by using `case=False` in `str.contains`